# The boundary of many points on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

everyone. Recently, we have encountered a problem about the boundary on Google Map.

We have received lots of points which are the objects as 'new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)'. Then, how to draw or make the boundary of this chunk. Or how to find the points (LatLng, used to draw the polygon) on the boundary, is there any JS arithmetic ?

Just like one story: we receive many sheep(points) as presents, so how to build the sheepfold with clear boundary for them ?

Thank you very much for any reply !!!

Comment: Is your question how to draw a polygon in google maps, or how to detect where to draw a polygon given a set of points?  If it's the latter, what constraints are there on the polygon?  Smallest circle you can draw?  Smallest rectangle?  Smallest n-sided?

Comment: Thank you for your question, what I want is something very simple: give you lots of points with different latlng, can you find those points on the MOST OUTER OUTLINE of this chunk ? So I can use these points to draw a polygon, and maybe the polygon is not a circle, but irregular shape !

Comment: And I mark these points on the most outer outline of this chunk : A ; the other points of this chunk is B. So I use A to draw one polygon, and the polygon contains B !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a "convex hull" algorithm.  Here's an example of one (you'll need to view source):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_map-markers_ConvexHull.asp

Here's a previous question about this as well:

[How to find/create Convex hull of GPS points in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589907/how-to-find-create-convex-hull-of-gps-points-in-javascript)

Comment: In fact I have got some algorithm to calculate the targets points on profile of this chunk. And it successed, thank you very much. The help   I greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

`var bound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();`
 and then extend the bound with
`bound.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));`

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I read the API, and it says: 'A LatLngBounds instance represents a rectangle in geographical coordinates'. Maybe I can use its center point and width to draw a fuzzy circle which covers all these points. But how can I find the most outer points of this chunk ? which can be used to draw polygon.

Comment: Well, if you provide the LatLngBounds your point it will return a rectangle. You feed with sheep it gives you the rectangle :)
Btw rectangle is represented by two points.

Comment: Yes. :) Using LatLngBounds to draw one circle which contains all the target points is suitable! And I can add some color character into this circle. Thank you very much !

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to ask again: give you lots of points with different latlng, can you find those points on the MOST OUTER OUTLINE of this chunk ? So I can use these points to draw a polygon, and maybe the polygon is not a circle, but irregular shape !